# How to get maximum value of multiple columns in a single row in LINQ?

Tags: linq

Say I have this table

MyTable

**ID**    **NumValue1**   **NumValue2**   **NumValue3**   **NumValue4**   **NumValue5**
1     12.17              23.97               *null*                 0.07               *null*
How to get the maximum value which is **23.97** from this single row using **LINQ** syntax?

In SQL (MS SQL) I can write something like this:

```
SELECT MaxNum = case 
when MyTable.NumValue1 is not null and
(MyTable.NumValue1 >= MyTable.NumValue2 or MyTable.NumValue2 is null) and
(MyTable.NumValue1 >= MyTable.NumValue3 or MyTable.NumValue3 is null) and
(MyTable.NumValue1 >= MyTable.NumValue4 or MyTable.NumValue4 is null) and
(MyTable.NumValue1 >= MyTable.NumValue5 or MyTable.NumValue5 is null) 
then MyTable.NumValue1
when MyTable.NumValue2 is not null and
(MyTable.NumValue2 >= MyTable.NumValue1 or MyTable.NumValue1 is null) and
(MyTable.NumValue2 >= MyTable.NumValue3 or MyTable.NumValue3 is null) and
(MyTable.NumValue2 >= MyTable.NumValue4 or MyTable.NumValue4 is null) and
(MyTable.NumValue2 >= MyTable.NumValue5 or MyTable.NumValue5 is null) 
then MyTable.NumValue2
when MyTable.NumValue3 is not null and
(MyTable.NumValue3 >= MyTable.NumValue1 or MyTable.NumValue1 is null) and
(MyTable.NumValue3 >= MyTable.NumValue2 or MyTable.NumValue2 is null) and
(MyTable.NumValue3 >= MyTable.NumValue4 or MyTable.NumValue4 is null) and
(MyTable.NumValue3 >= MyTable.NumValue5 or MyTable.NumValue5 is null) 
then MyTable.NumValue3
when MyTable.NumValue4 is not null and
(MyTable.NumValue4 >= MyTable.NumValue1 or MyTable.NumValue1 is null) and
(MyTable.NumValue4 >= MyTable.NumValue2 or MyTable.NumValue2 is null) and
(MyTable.NumValue4 >= MyTable.NumValue3 or MyTable.NumValue3 is null) and
(MyTable.NumValue4 >= MyTable.NumValue5 or MyTable.NumValue5 is null) 
then MyTable.NumValue4
when MyTable.NumValue5 is not null and
(MyTable.NumValue5 >= MyTable.NumValue1 or MyTable.NumValue1 is null) and
(MyTable.NumValue5 >= MyTable.NumValue2 or MyTable.NumValue2 is null) and
(MyTable.NumValue5 >= MyTable.NumValue3 or MyTable.NumValue3 is null) and
(MyTable.NumValue5 >= MyTable.NumValue4 or MyTable.NumValue4 is null) 
then MyTable.NumValue5
else null
end
FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.ID=1;
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your `DataTable` looks like this:

```
var t = new DataTable();
t.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
t.Columns.Add("NumValue1", typeof(decimal));
t.Columns.Add("NumValue2", typeof(decimal));
t.Columns.Add("NumValue3", typeof(decimal));
t.Columns.Add("NumValue4", typeof(decimal));
t.Columns.Add("NumValue5", typeof(decimal));
```

and your row looks like this:

```
var row = t.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, 
                                   12.17m, 
                                   23.97m, 
                                   DBNull.Value,
                                    0.07m, 
                                   DBNull.Value});
```

you can get the maximum value with this query:

```
// get all values:
var max = row.ItemArray 
           // only values that are not DBNull:
           .Where(o => o != DBNull.Value) 
                  // convert to decimal and get the max value:
                  .Max(o => Convert.ToDecimal(o));
```

`max` is now `23.97`

Comment: Thanks.I'm very new at LINQ. I believed this is lambda expression. How this will look like in normal LINQ? Thanks again.

Comment: @mADy1270 you mean in query syntax? You could use something like `var max = (from o in row.ItemArray where o != DBNull.Value select Convert.ToDecimal(o)).Max()`

Comment: Yes. This is what I'm looking for.But looking at this, it looks like it evaluating all columns in the row. What if I just interested in getting the MAX from columns NumValue1, NumValue2 and NumValue3, but not columns NumValue4 and NumValue5. Thanks

Comment: If you're only interested in the first 3 columns, you could do something like `row.ItemArray.Take(3).Where(....`.